# Append multiple columns to one string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching for the best way to do that:
I have table with columns ID, network1, network2....30.
the value in the column is true or false.
I want to get string with network numbers for all row when the value is true.

like this:

```
"5,7,8"
```

when the values in network5 and network7 and network8 are true and the others is false.

can you please advise?

Comment: Have you considered using MySQL's [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html) datatype instead?

Comment: Or rather a normalisation (store id - network pairs in their own record)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using multiple `IF`'s combined with `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT t.id,
       concat(IF(t.network1 = 'TRUE','1,',''),
              IF(t.network2 = 'TRUE','2,',''),
              IF(t.network3 = 'TRUE','3,',''),
              IF(t.network4 = 'TRUE','4,',''),
              .....
FROM YourTable t
```